# Opening a folder with a variable in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a script to run a function for me based on files I download from my site every day.

Basically, my site creates a folder based on the date (yyyy, mm, dd).  I want applescript to first open that folder, and then run the action on each folder/file inside.

Trouble is, when I try to point my script to that folder using a variable, it gives me the error: Can't make path name into a constant.

Maybe the REAL problem is how new I am to this!  Here's what I've tried:

```
    tell application "Finder"
    set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)
    set theTime to y & m & d
    set pathToTarget to path to theTime
    open folder pathToTarget of folder "F-grams" of folder "files" of folder "default" of folder "sites" of folder "foldagram" of folder "htdocs" of folder "MAMP" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
end tell
```

Who wants to help a newbie get on track?
-JB

Comment: this line generates the error: "set pathToTarget to path to theTime" --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder action will be triggered every time a new item is added to the target folder. The second repeat block will allow you to send commands for each item within each added folder. You may reference each one of these items with the anItem variable. Save the script in the Folder Action Scripts folder in your Library. Be sure to attach the folder action to the target folder.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFolders
    try
        repeat with aFolder in theFolders
            tell application "Finder" to set myItems to every item of aFolder
            repeat with anItem in myItems
                -- Insert your code here
            end repeat
        end repeat
    on error errMsg number errNum
        tell me
            activate
            display alert errMsg & return & return & "Error number" & errNum buttons "Cancel"
        end tell
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

However, if you wanted to search for folders by date, this is how you should format the date string:

```
set delimiter to ", "
set aDate to (current date)
set aYear to (year of aDate) as string
set aMonth to (month of aDate as integer) as string
if length of aMonth is 1 then set aMonth to "0" & aMonth
set aDay to (day of aDate as integer) as string
if length of aDay is 1 then set aDay to "0" & aDay
set theTime to aYear & delimiter & aMonth & delimiter & aDay as string
```